# change launch image(default.png)?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i am quite new to iphone development but i have been given a old application and told to change the launch image(default.png)..i tried to google it but couldn't get much help from it??
how can i change the default image in my old application?? any information regarding it will be really helpful??

Comment: do you have the source code? or just the binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term is splash screen and I'm sure that's why you weren't seeing any good search results.  Here is a good link:

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/06/22/creating-splash-screen-tutorial-for-iphone/

Comment: actually, the term is launch image. see the HIG.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it programmatically. You can make a new one and just replace Default.png file with it.

Comment: just replacing the old image with new default.png image will do it??

Comment: Yes. Why you think it won't do it?